# Reload stylesheets in PyQT / PySide after change object name

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Good day, colleagues, I have a styles, example:

```
#button_1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#button_2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I have 3 objects:

```
button_1 = QPushButton()
button_2 = QPushButton()
button_3 = QPushButton()
```

And I want after click on `button_1` set to this button style #button_1, I change the name of this button

```
button_1.setObjectName('button_1')
```

but after it button style not change, (but css load correct it's worked), and I have a question, maybe I need to reload or do smth with this button to set this style for it and it should be work.

I use python version 3.10 and pyside6 version 6.4.1

Full code of app:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
import sys


class App(QWidget):
    

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("""
                           #button_1 {
                             background-color: green;
                           }

                           #button_2 {
                             background-color: red;
                           }
                           """)

        self.button_1 = QPushButton()
        self.button_2 = QPushButton()
        self.button_3 = QPushButton()

        self.app_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.app_layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.app_layout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.app_layout.addWidget(self.button_3)

        self.setLayout(self.app_layout)

        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.button_1_click)

    def button_1_click(self):
        print('clicked')
        self.button_1.setObjectName('button_1')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window_widget = App()    
    main_window_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Changing object name at runtime isn't a very good idea, and doing it for style changes is not really the intended purpose of object names. Can you clarify what are you actually trying to achieve, explaining the *practical* needs of what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correctly work all styles, after change the name I make reload all styles. Example:

In app class I add:

```
def load_styles(self):
    with open('styles.css', 'r') as file:
        self.setStyleSheet(file.read())
```

After that, after change the name, I call this method:

```
def button_1_click(self):
    print('clicked')
    self.button_1.setObjectName('button_1')
    self.load_styles()
```

Not good solve, but another I doesn't have :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try changing the name and then parsing the stylesheet.

Also instead make the stylesheet button specific so that when you call it its like this:

```
self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #8a78f0; border-style: none; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 5px; ")
```

This will change the widget specifically by calling it onto the object.

Also please provide more code so that we can reproduce the error as I don't not have enough information to provide optimal assistance.

However, using a specific stylesheet like the code above may do the trick.

Comment: Add a full code, now test your solve

Comment: Yeah, it's work, but all styles I keep in file, and how can I automate this step with file? Maybe reload all styles? I try it now

Comment: Yeah, it's work. If I reload styles after change the name. Thank you for helping me to get this solve!

Comment: @antipups Does this solve your question as you have said that it works but also the question is not marked answered and beneath you have added code and said that it has not worked. Please clarify.

Comment: Correctly, I write a answer below, I wait when I can mark it, cause in this message I present how I make it work with code, not on words